# Failed to Install SQL Server MDS Workflow Integration Service

Tags: sql-server, mds

I tried to create a custom workflow by the following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/develop/create-a-custom-workflow-master-data-services.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data
>   Services\WebApplication\bin>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil
>   Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe
>   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework
>   Installation utility Version 4.7.2053.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data
>   Services\WebApplication\bin\Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.

Any advice?
I'm running CMD with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just select 64 bit version.